# MySQL group rows by one column sorting by another column

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, select, group-by

I'm developing a PHP script, and I have the following table:

```
+----+-----------+----------+--------------+
| id | id_parent | position |  feature     |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+
| 1  |     1     |    2     |   -B-A-C-    |
| 2  |     1     |    3     |   -B-C-      |
| 3  |     2     |    4     |   -C-B-      |
| 4  |     3     |    1     |   -A-B-      |
| 5  |     1     |    6     |   -A-C-      |
| 6  |     2     |    5     |   -C-B-      |
| 7  |     2     |    7     |   -B-C-      |
| 8  |     3     |    8     |   -A-        |
+----+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

From this table I would like to select all the rows with "feature" LIKE "%-A-%", but displaying first the result with lowest "position", then all the rows that have same value for column "id_parent" of the first result, then row with the 2nd lowest "position" and all the rows that have same "id_parent" of the result with the 2nd lowest "position", and so on...
So the final result should be:

```
+----+-----------+----------+--------------+
| id | id_parent | position |   feature    |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+
| 4  |     3     |    1     |   -A-B-      |
| 8  |     3     |    8     |   -A-        |
| 1  |     1     |    2     |   -B-A-C-    |    
| 5  |     1     |    6     |   -A-C-      |
+----+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

For some reason I can't explain here I need to have and HAVING clause for selecting the right "feature" value (...HAVING 'feature' LIKE '%-A-%' ...).

Is it possible to make all this with MySQL (possibly without subqueries) or by processing data results with PHP?

Comment: This is a drastic step backwards. This is a poor design. If you have multiple features, then consider storing them, normalised, in a separate table - with a separate row for each feature.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? I've left the last part of the problem as an exercise for the reader...

```
SELECT a.*
     , c.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id_parent, MIN(position) position FROM my_table WHERE feature = 'a' GROUP BY id_parent ) b 
    ON b.id_parent = a.id_parent 
   AND b.position = a.position 
  JOIN my_table c 
    ON c.feature = a.feature 
   AND c.id_parent = a.id_parent;
```

Comment: Hi, I changed my reply cause my actual need is to use a LIKE for the "feature" column, not a simple = comparing.